# list-comprehension-like expansion inside Julia expression?

Tags: julia

Is it possible to have something like a list comprehension for building complicated expressions in Julia?

For example, say I have some symbols and types, and want to build a type from them. Right now, I have to do something like.

```
syms = [:a, :b, :c]
typs = [Int, Float32, Char]
new_type = :(type Foo end)
new_type.args[3].args = [:($sym::$typ) for (sym,typ) in zip(syms,typs)]
```

This works in that `new_type` is an expression containing

```
:(type Foo
    a::Int64
    b::Float32
    c::Char
end)
```

But building complicated expressions like this is both extremely error prone (because you have be intimately knowledgeable with the `Expr` data type in order to know, eg that the expressions for the data types of the tuple have to be stored in `new_type.args[3].args`) and also extremely brittle in that any change to the AST of the expression being built would mean having to change where/how every sub-expression is stored.

So is there a way to do something like

```
:(type Foo
    $(sym::typ for (sym,typ) in zip(syms,typs))
end)
```

and end up with the same expression as above?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can splat arrays of expressions directly into the syntax:

```
julia> :(type Foo
           $([:($sym::$typ) for (sym,typ) in zip(syms,typs)]...)
       end)
:(type Foo # none, line 2:
        a::Int64
        b::Float32
        c::Char
    end)
```

Comment: Thanks, I think I was on the right track, just couldn't get the syntax right.